# Move Purview Assets using API

Tags: azure, powershell, api, atlas, azure-purview

I have a Purview account and inside that there are many collections and inside those collections there are assets.

Now I want to move few assets from one collection to another which is possible from GUI(Azure Portal).

Now I am exploring if there is any way to move them using API and PowerShell.

Please help me on this and let me know if you need any further details.

Below is the code snippet which I am trying but its not working.

```
$tenantID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/token"
$params = @{ client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; client_secret = 
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; grant_type = "client_credentials"; resource 
= ‘https://purview.azure.net’ }

$bearertoken = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Post -Body $params - 
UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json

$headers = @{
  Authorization="Bearer " + $bearertoken.access_token
  Content='application/json'
}

$endpoint = "https://testpurview.purview.azure.com"
$url1 = 
"$endpoint/catalog/api/collections/mycollectionname/entity/moveHere?api- 
 version=2022-03-01-preview"

$guids = @"
{
   "entityGuids": [
      "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    ]
  }
"@
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri $url1 -Body $guids -ContentType 
'application/json' -Headers $headers
```

Getting below error,

Invoke-WebRequest: C:\Repos\Purview\PurviewAutomation\Move_assets.ps1:23:1
Line |
23 |  Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri $url1 -Body $guids -ContentType ' …
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| {"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Not authorized to access account"}}

Comment: You can check this API -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/collection/move-entities-to-collection?tabs=HTTP and this one to update the existing collection with new asset:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/collection/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am new to API. Is there any example like how can we use this API using powershell.

Comment: Okay, Did you try any Powershell code on your end, If yes, Can you update that in your question? So, I can test it on my end?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the below **Powershell script** to call the Microsoft Purview API, I received unauthorized error like below:-

Error:-

> Invoke-RestMethod :
> {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client
> 'xxxxx' with object  id
> 'xxxxxx' does not have authorization to
> perform action 'Microsoft.Purview/operations/write' over  scope
> '/providers/Microsoft.Purview' or the scope is invalid. If access was
> recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}

[image]

I added the service principal used to call the API as a ***Collection Admins, Data Source Admins and Data curators*** refer below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Added API permissions for Azure AD app for Purview*** like below:-

[image]

Ran the below code to **CREATE/UPDATE the collection in Purview**:-

```
$AppId="<client-id>"
$AppSecret="<client-secret>"
$TokenURI="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token"
$Resource="https://purview.azure.net"


$BodyRequest="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$AppId&client_secret=$AppSecret&resource=$Resource"

$AccessToken=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $TokenURI `
-Body $BodyRequest -ContentType  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$RequestURI="

https://<purview-account>.purview.azure.com/catalog/api/collections/<collection>/entity?api-version=2022-03-01-preview"

$body = @"
{
  "referredEntities": {},
  "entity": {
    "typeName": "azure_storage_account",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "exampleaccount",
      "qualifiedName": "https://exampleaccount.core.windows.net"
    }
  }
}
"@

$Headers=@{} 

$Headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer " + $AccessToken.access_token) 
  
$Result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RequestURI -Headers $Headers -Method POST -Body $body -Verbose -ContentType 'application/json')


Write-Host $Result
```

Output:-

[image]

***The storage account collection got added to the Purview account like below:-***

[image]

You can update the entity to another collection by changing the collection name in the above API call.

To **Move** the Entity refer the code below:-

```
$AppId="<client-id>"
$AppSecret="<client-secret>"
$TokenURI="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token"

$Resource="https://purview.azure.net"


$BodyRequest="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$AppId&client_secret=$AppSecret&resource=$Resource"

$AccessToken=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $TokenURI `
-Body $BodyRequest -ContentType  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'



$RequestURI="
https://<purview-account>.purview.azure.com/catalog/api/collections/<purviewcollection>/entity/moveHere?api-version=2022-03-01-preview"

$guids = @"
{
   "entityGuids": [
      "aa4d2ab0-f3da-48d5-b1e9-2fd718df7fed"
    ]
  }
"@

$Headers=@{} 

$Headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer " + $AccessToken.access_token) 
  
$Result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RequestURI -Headers $Headers -Method POST -Body $guids -Verbose -ContentType 'application/json')



Write-Host $Result
```

Output:-

[image]

Reference:-

[Collection - Create Or Update - REST API (Azure Purview) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/collection/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#)

[Collection - Move Entities To Collection - REST API (Azure Purview) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/collection/move-entities-to-collection?tabs=HTTP)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think, I have missed to grant API permission on SPN for the Purview. Could you please tell me what permission(read & write?) you have granted for that?

Comment: I have added Purview.DelegatedAccess permissions and then Granted Admin Consent. Along with that, I have added Collection Admins, Data Source Admins and Data curator roles to the SPN

Comment: you granted Admin Consent on Delegated permission or Application permission because the screenshot you shared Admin Consent is set to No on the delegated permission tab.

Comment: I added Delegated permissions and in my environment, The Admin consent is not required for the application - https://i.imgur.com/orjDoqe.png that's the reason it is showing, Admin consent required as No

Comment: Apologies, I couldn't respond to it. Yes its worked for me. Thanks a lot.